# Problemas con SQLite

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

buenas tardes, simplemente trato de traducir y saber que dicen los codigos de ejemplos para poder entender mejor como funciona cada cosa, y quede trancado en este fregmentom, es parte de un codigo para una base de datos con multi tabla en android studio, el codigo es el siguiente..

(todo lo saco de este ejercicio http://instinctcoder.com/android-studio-sqlite-database-multiple-tables-example/ y mi intencion es aprender hacer base de datos multitablas en sqlite para android studio UU)

quiero saber que hace o que significa y como se lee la linea, que es el `getSimpleName();`?

```
public static final String TAG = Course.class.getSimpleName();
```

en esta class

```
package com.instinctcoder.sqlitedbmultitbl.data.model;

/**
* Created by Tan on 1/26/2016.
*/
public class Course {

public static final String TAG = Course.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String TABLE = "Course";
// Labels Table Columns names
public static final String KEY_CourseId = "CourseId";
public static final String KEY_Name = "Name";

private String courseId;
private String name;


public String getCourseId() {
    return courseId;
}

public void setCourseId(String courseId) {
    this.courseId = courseId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

y luego... en este bloque desconozco los fulanos "`data.repo`" que luego los usa como...

```
    db.execSQL(CourseRepo.createTable());
    db.execSQL(StudentRepo.createTable());
    db.execSQL(MajorRepo.createTable());
    db.execSQL(StudentCourseRepo.createTable());
```

en la clase..

```
package com.instinctcoder.sqlitedbmultitbl.data;

/**
 * Created by Tan on 1/26/2016.
 */
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.instinctcoder.sqlitedbmultitbl.app.App;
import com.instinctcoder.sqlitedbmultitbl.data.model.Course;
import com.instinctcoder.sqlitedbmultitbl.data.model.Major;
import com.instinctcoder.sqlitedbmultitbl.data.model.Student;
import com.instinctcoder.sqlitedbmultitbl.data.model.StudentCourse;
import com.instinctcoder.sqlitedbmultitbl.data.repo.CourseRepo;
import com.instinctcoder.sqlitedbmultitbl.data.repo.MajorRepo;
import com.instinctcoder.sqlitedbmultitbl.data.repo.StudentCourseRepo;
import com.instinctcoder.sqlitedbmultitbl.data.repo.StudentRepo;


public class DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
//version number to upgrade database version
//each time if you Add, Edit table, you need to change the
//version number.
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =8;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sqliteDBMultiTbl.db";
private static final String TAG = DBHelper.class.getSimpleName().toString();

public DBHelper( ) {
    super(App.getContext(), DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //All necessary tables you like to create will create here
    db.execSQL(CourseRepo.createTable());
    db.execSQL(StudentRepo.createTable());
    db.execSQL(MajorRepo.createTable());
    db.execSQL(StudentCourseRepo.createTable());
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("SQLiteDatabase.onUpgrade(%d -> %d)", oldVersion, newVersion));

    // Drop table if existed, all data will be gone!!!
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Course.TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Student.TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Major.TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + StudentCourse.TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

}
```

Comment: la pregunta principal que haces es muy general y el ejemplo poco tiene que ver. Lo encuentras mucho mejor explicado y sin esperar en Google :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La intrucción `CualquierClase.class.getSimpleName()` retorna el nombre de la clase como un `String`(en tu caso `"Course"`), existe otra función llamada `getName` que obtiene el nombre completo de la clase, es decir, el nombre del paquete más el nombre de la clase(En tu caso `"com.instinctcoder.sqlitedbmultitbl.data.model.Course"`). Esto no tiene nada que ver sqlite, es parte del estandar de java.

La variable `TAG` usada en tu código recibe ese valor, ya que despues lo usas como medio de depuración con la siguiente instrucción:

```
Log.d(TAG,..)
```

Está última expresión te permitira leer la información que coloques en tiempo de ejecución del programa. En tu caso tienes el siguiente código en el método `onUpgrade` que se ejecuta cuando actualizas la versión de base de datos:

```
Log.d(TAG, String.format("SQLiteDatabase.onUpgrade(%d -> %d)", oldVersion, newVersion));
```

Este imprimira los valores de la versión anterior y nueva versión.

Answer (score 0):

> que es el getSimpleName();?
>
> [getSimpleName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html) : Devuelve el nombre simple de la clase
>   subyacente como se indica en el código fuente. Devuelve una cadena
>   vacía si la clase subyacente es anónima.

En este caso simplemente obtiene el nombre de la clase para ser usada como etiqueta al imprimir datos dentro del `LogCat`:

```
public static final String TAG = Course.class.getSimpleName();
```

En este caso es lo mismo que si escribieras simplemente :

```
public static final String TAG ="Course";
```